# Why is my ListView not showing the new data?

Tags: android, listview

my problem is, that I have a ListView and a ArrayAdapter. Now I create the adapter like this:

```
items = OtherClass.DataSet1;
adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.mein_listitem, items);
```

then I want to change the items e.g:

```
items = OtherClass.DataSet2;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But the result is, that I still see the DataSet1 items in my ListView and I dont know why.

I have the following whole code:

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ArrayList<Item> items;
    MyArrayAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        items = OtherClass.DataSet1;
        adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.mein_listitem, items);

        {...}
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {

        if (arg0.getText().equals(getText(R.string.foo))) {
            items = OtherClass.DataSet1;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            items = OtherClass.DataSet2;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class Item {
    public Item(String foo1) {
        super();
        Foo1 = foo1;

    }

    public String Foo1;

}
```

Comment: What is this items = OtherClass.DataSet1; ??

Comment: just repeat this after notifyChange `adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.mein_listitem, items);`

Comment: you have to assign new item values to adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your items on your `ArrayAdapter` object via the `.add()` or `.addAll()` methods. This will actually append the objects you've provided as parameters to the dataset already showing up.

```
adapter.add(...);
adapter.addAll(...);
```

And (as you done), don't forget always calling `.notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after adding items to it.